# Non public api usage iOS App - Invalid Binary

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, xctestcase

Whenever i try to upload a binary, Apple is giving me this error. Last month, I uploaded a version and it got successfully uploaded, i have not made many changes in the code in this version - just minor bug fixes, but now, it's giving me this error. Please help.

Email by Apple :

Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "Schoofi". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

Non-public API usage:

The app contains or inherits from non-public classes in Schoofi: XCTestCase
If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed.

If you think this message was sent in error and that you have only used Apple-published APIs in accordance with the guidelines, send the app's nine-digit Apple ID, along with detailed information about why you believe the above APIs were incorrectly flagged, to appreview@apple.com. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information page.

Once these issues have been corrected, you can then redeliver the corrected binary.

Regards,

The App Store team

Comment: Do not post an image of the email. Please replace the image with the actual text. An image is hard to read, and it can't be reference or searched.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for your comment. Now, please see and help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include `XCTestCase` in your apps binary. Tests don't need to be apart of the submitted binary. Make sure the test classes are only included in your test bundle and not your apps bundle, by checking the appropriate check boxes in the file inspector on the right pane in Xcode.

Comment: I tried by removing Unit test from my project and still the same error. How will i know where is the exact problem ? What is the exact problem? Apple is not replying to my mails. They suck in terms of these kind of services !!

Comment: The error has to be from XCTestCase, but apple won't point you to the exact class or line. It could also be from a library or dependency that has included this API.

Comment: Yes. I was using extra file of XCTestCase. I just removed it and it worked !